# Изменение интервалов проверки в Nagios

Tags: unix, мониторинг

Nagios проверяет все со слишком большим интервалом (несколько минут).

Как уменьшить интервал проверок?

Например, до 5 секунд, т.е., чтобы он каждые 5 секунд все опрашивал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

согласно [документации](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/configmain.html#interval_length), глобальная переменная `interval_length` определяет, какому промежутку времени кратны различные интервалы (`check_interval` и т.п.), указанные в описании различных объектов (`host` и т.п.).

по умолчанию эта переменная равно 60 (секундам). и автор (документации) честно предупреждает:

> I have not really tested other values for this variable, so proceed at your own risk if you decide to do so!

мой вольный перевод:

> вообще-то я не тестировал другие значения этой переменной, так что, если вы решили это сделать, действуйте на свой страх и риск!